# some files get lost in input mount of docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a mount a directory in an input mount of Docker container (Directory contains my files).

Inside the container, I list mounted files at the beginning and at the middle of my script. The problem is some files do not get mounted.

Sometimes, I can't see some of them at the beginning of my script or All of them are in input mount at the beginning of script but some of them are not in input mount at the middle of script sometimes.

What is the problem?

***P.S:I mostly faced this problem while bulk launch***

Comment: What is your OS? Are you using named or bind-mounted volumes? Are you mounting a directory or individual files?

Comment: I use centos 7. I mount directory (my files are inside directory). We use bind mounts only

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]